# How to navigate to URL in JavaScript using if

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to validate whether text box is filled with some text or not. In case when there is not any characters typed, alert (`alert("Name must be filled out");`) working well but, else condition, when some characters are entered (`else window.location.href = 'http://www.w3schools.com';`) doesn't forward to URL.

Could you please advise some methods? Thanks in advance.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["registration"]["name"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
       alert("Name must be filled out");
     return false;
 } else window.location.href = 'http://www.w3schools.com';
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="registration"   method="post" >
Name <input type="text" name="name" />
<br>
<button type="Submit" name="submit" onClick="validateForm()"  >Submit</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Running the code snippet it works dude

Comment: I agree with @Lokuzt. It works.

Comment: I would suggest using curly brackets more consistently; namely, having them around the `else` clause in addition to the `if` clause.

Answer (score 1):

The live snippet you've provided doesn't actually reproduce the problem because form submissions are blocked:

> Blocked form submission to 'http://stacksnippets.net/js' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.

Elsewhere, it doesn't forward to the URL because after the JavaScript has finished running, the form submits which triggers a new page load (this replaces the new page load that assigning a new value to `location` triggered).

You would need to return `false` from the `onclick` function or not use a submit button to trigger the JS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for answers, I solve problem by changing button "type"

```html
<button type="button" name="submit" onClick="validateForm()"  >Submit</button>
```